# Django - Template objects access verbose name

Tags: html, django, templates

I have a `Scrib` model and a template which gets `Scrib.objects.all()` stored into `scribs`

In the template, I'd like to access to the verbose name of the model like:

```
<h1>{{ scribs.model.verbose_name }}</h1>
```

Is it possible or do I have to add the `Scrib` handler to the context ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't access the verbose_name directly from the template. From what I see you got three options.

Option one (simplest). Assign the verbose name in your controller and then access it from the template:

```
# in controller
render_to_response('template.html', {'scrib_verbose_name': Scrib._meta.verbose_name})

# in a view template.html
Verbose name of a Scrib model: {{ scrib_verbose_name }}
```

Option two: write yourself a view helper that will return the verbose_name (or other field from _meta class) for a given class.

**Update** Third option (a hat tip to Uku Loskit) - define a method on a scrib model that returns the meta object (or any particular field from it).

```
# method in a Scrib model
def meta(self):
    return self._meta

# later on in a template - scrib is a instance of Scrib model
<h1>{{ scrib.meta.verbose_name }}</h1>
```

**Update2** If you insist on directly accessing verbose name from the `scribs` (which is a result of `Scrib.objects.all()`), then you can do stuff like:

```
scribs = Scrib.objects.all()
scribs.verbose_name = Scrib._meta.verbose_name

# in a template you can now access verbose name from a scribs variable
{{ scribs.verbose_name }}
```

**Update3** Yet another way to go is using model inhertinace to be able to access the verbose name from instance of any model that inherit from our custom one.

```
# base model (inherits from models.Model)
class CustomModel(models.Model):
    def meta(self):
        return self._meta

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# Scrib now inherit from CustomModel
class Scrib(CustomModel):
    # do any stuff you want here ...
```

Scrib now inherit from CustomModel that provides us with property *meta*. Any model that will inherit from CustomModel class is going to have this property. It's the cleanest and most flexible solution.

Comment: Actually `scribs` is equal to `Scrib.objects.all()` so it's a multiple object. Do I have to put `Scrib` instead `Scrib.objects.all()` into `scribs` ?

Comment: Well if you loop in your template through scribs then you can use `.meta.verbose_name` on every instance of scrib in a loop. If you want  to display it just once (before actual looping for example) you can do  simply `{{ scribs.0.meta.verbose_name }}` to display a verbose name using the first scrib in a scribs array.

Comment: Couldn't I put directly the model `Scrib` into `scribs`, loop through `scribs.objects.all` and use `scribs.verbose_name` or something simpler ? Otherwise will I have to put this function on all of my models ?

Comment: You're overcomplicating things or I just don't get what you want :) Anyhow - I've updated my answer once again

Comment: I'm trying to have something maintainable. If I use `scribs.verbose_name = Scrib._meta.verbose_name` it's pushing the problem into the view. Each time I need to access to the verbose name I have make a modification somewhere. But if there is no other way I'll do that.

Comment: Ok, yet another solution is in my answer - this time model inheritance to provide access to meta data from any model. Keep in mind, that from what I understand you're trying to access information reserved to model class from the QuerySet object which is basically a list of those models. It's better in my opinion to keep this information (and retrieve it) directly from a model.

Comment: Your 4th solution seems better to me :) Thanks

Comment: I like the Update (3rd soln). Obvious once I thought about it. Good work.

Answer (score 8):

I want to do that as well, I suppose another solution would be a template filter:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def verbose_name(value):
    return value._meta.verbose_name

@register.filter
def verbose_name_plural(value):
    return value._meta.verbose_name_plural
```

Then in the template:

```
1 {{ object|verbose_name }}, 2 {{ object|verbose_name_plural }}

1 scrib, 2 scribs
```

Comment: This appears to result in `'str' object has no attribute '_meta'` in Django 3.0

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively to WTK's suggestion you could define a method for the Scrib model in your `models.py` like this:

```
def get_verbose_name(self):
    return self._meta.verbose_name
# in templates
{{ scrib_instance.get_verbose_name }}
```

Comment: Do I have to create this method for all the objects where I need the verbose name or is there a simpler way ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY You can have a base abstract model and have all your models extend from it.  Write once, use all over.